# Is there a reason why detox tests are stuck at this point without changing anything inside the code ( they were all working fine )

Tags: reactjs, react-native, end-to-end, detox

[image: it's built correctly, and the commands are correct, is there any other logical reason?]
it's built correctly, and the commands are correct, is there any other logical reason?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCv68.png)

[image]

Comment: That can issued by many problems. Please provide more information.
For which OS the test is running?
Can you run the test with —log-level trace ?
What’s the log output.

Comment: Failing on both IOS / Android , working on android for now ,sure thing , @MichaelBahl

Comment: Does it work now on android?

1. Did you start the packager separately? If not you should do so
2. What are your timeouts ?
3. How long does the test take until it fails?